# Selecting a radio button among two radio group buttons

Tags: android

I have 2 radiogroups containing 5 radio buttons each.
At any time only one radio button out of 10 has to be selected. I wrote the code below, and it works some time and not always. Help needed.Thanks

```
radGrp1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {       
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {


              id =arg0.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
             RadioButton selectedRedioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
             selectedRedioButton.setChecked(true);
             int checkedRadioButtonID = radGrp2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected "+selectedRedioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             int checkedRadioButtonID2 = radGrp2.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); 
             if (checkedRadioButtonID2 != -1) {
                 RadioButton selectedRedioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonID2);
                 selectedRedioButton2.setChecked(false);     
             }

        }




    });

    radGrp2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {


            id =arg0.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
             RadioButton selectedRedioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
             selectedRedioButton.setChecked(true);
             int checkedRadioButtonID = radGrp2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected "+selectedRedioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             int checkedRadioButtonID1 = radGrp1.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); 
             if (checkedRadioButtonID1 != -1) {
                RadioButton selectedRedioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonID1);
                selectedRedioButton1.setChecked(false);          

             }

        }


    });
```

Comment: "and it works some time and not always".  Define what you mean by this.  When it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: why do you use two radio groups if you want to select only one at a time..?use just one radio group instead..

Comment: dint get you @user3680860

Comment: @Lal If my first selection is on a radion button under grp2, then I am abe to select on the radio buttons under grp2. None of the radio buttons under grp1 get selected.

Comment: that means if any of the radiobuttons in group1 is selected then 2nd radiogroup has to be disabled and vice versa..right???

Comment: @Lal: Yes you are right...